# Change Sonata Admin Logo based on database record

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I have a module for manage images inside my Sonata Admin. I want to display those images where sonata logo is placed, how I can do that? I have the code for get the images in my controller and also the template to display the image but don't know how to use this from Sonata, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the sonate base template (like you overide any other template) or any block listed inside of it.

there is a block called `logo` and it looks like this

```
{% block logo %}
  <a href="{{ url('sonata_admin_dashboard') }}" class="brand">
    <img src="{{ asset(admin_pool.titlelogo) }}"  alt="{{ admin_pool.title }}" />
    {{ admin_pool.title }}
  </a>
{% endblock %}
```

In combination with a Twig-Extension it should be no problem to fetch the image out of the database